# custom post template not getting picked for posts with Unicode title

Tags: custom-post-types, template-hierarchy

We have a custom post type called `support`.
And we have created a template for it as `single-support.php`.

The problem is when we crate a new post with English slug it works fine:
eg. `www.mywebsite.com/support/a-new-article/`

But when we create a new page with a Unicode title(slug), the template hierarchy is not working like the English slug:
eg. `www.mywebsite.com/support/සාමන්ය-පිටුවක්/`

Comment: [Template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post) doesn't have anything with `title`, but with the `slug`. If you have template with `single-{posttype}.php` then it shouldn't be happened. So I think it's not legit. Let's [debug from the very beginning](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/debug/info) again.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam  Actually post slug generated from the title(I know we can change the slug. But it is not an option for this requirement). Yes we have template naming correct. Thats why said if we have English slug its pick the correct template this only happens when we use unicode slug. Thanks